# Question related to potential closed-form representation of Catalan's constant

Tags: number-theory, closed-form, dirichlet-series, catalans-constant

The motivation for this question is to find a closed-form representation for [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant). Formula (1) below for the [Dirichlet beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function) $\beta(s)$ (which I believe is globally convergent) leads to formulas (2), (3), and (4) below for Catalan's constant $G=\beta(2)$.

---

$$\beta(s)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^K\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k\ \binom{n}{k}}{(2 k+1)^s}\right)\tag{1}$$

---

$$G=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^K\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k\ \binom{n}{k}}{(2 k+1)^2}\right)\tag{2}$$

$$G=\underset{K\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{8}\sum\limits_{n=0}^K\frac{n! \left(H_{n+\frac{1}{2}}+\log (4)\right)}{2^n\ \Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}\right)\tag{3}$$

$$G=\underset{K\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{8}\left(\sqrt{\pi} \log (4)+\sum\limits_{n=0}^K \frac{n!\ H_{n+\frac{1}{2}}}{2^n\ \Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}\right)\right)\tag{4}$$

---

> **Question**: Is there a closed form representation for formula (5) below?

---

$$G=\underset{K\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^K \frac{n!\ H_{n+\frac{1}{2}}}{2^n\ \Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}\right)=1.6770831981...\tag{5}$$

---

I tried using the following identity for the [Harmonic number function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) but this just led to a more complicated infinite series over [Hypergeometric PFQ Regularized functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedHypergeometricFunction.html).

---

$$H_{n+\frac{1}{2}}=\sum _{m=1}^{\infty } \frac{n+\frac{1}{2}}{m \left(m+n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\tag{6}$$

Comment: Usually, a sum of a hypergeometric function, in a hypergeometric series, would be in terms of the [Kampé](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7if9e.gif) [de Feriét](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KampedeFerietFunction.html) function or a simpler sum would be in terms of [Appell Hypergeometric functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AppellHypergeometricFunction.html) which may simplify into simpler functions.